# Using GET in a Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf

I have a question regarding Django Forms and GET

I have a form to download student scores in CSV format. The fields are name and year so I have a **forms.py**

```
StudentDownloadForm(forms.Form):
  name=forms.CharField()
  year = forms.CharField()
```

And I want to use this form in the **template.html** with

`context={'student_form' : StudentDownloadForm(),}`

```
<form action ="" method="GET">
  {% csrf_token %}{{ student_form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" value="Query"/>
</form>
```

So my questions are as follows:

- If I use the `method="GET"` then the csrf token is visible in the URL, which is a security issue
- Can I then use the `method="POST"` instead?
- Alternatively, can I remove the csrf token in the form?

Comment: A GET does not require a CSRF token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Django documentation ([Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)):

> For all incoming requests that are **not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   or TRACE**, a CSRF cookie must be present, and the ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’
>   field must be present and correct. If it isn’t, the user will get a
>   403 error.

And:

> **It deliberately ignores GET requests (and other requests that are
>   defined as ‘safe’ by RFC 2616)**. These requests ought never to have any
>   potentially dangerous side effects , and so a CSRF attack with a GET
>   request ought to be harmless. RFC 2616 defines POST, PUT and DELETE as
>   ‘unsafe’, and all other methods are assumed to be unsafe, for maximum
>   protection.

So, you can omit CSRF token for GET requiests

Comment: You can, but you must make sure you stick to the standard and [do not use GET for "unsafe" requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).